# ASP.NET: Image not displaying

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
    Protected Sub Upload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Upload.Click
    If Me.FileUpload1.HasFile Then

        Dim intWidth, intHeight As Integer
        Dim UlFileName, NewFileName As String

        intWidth = 200 '*** Fix Width ***'  
        intHeight = 0   '*** If = 0 Auto Re-Cal Size ***'  
        'intHeight = 120

        If Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower <> ".gif" Then
            'Pop Up. File needs to be a GIF
            vLabel.Text = "Only .GIF files allowed. Please convert your image to a .GIF"

        Else

            UlFileName = "\\bk00app0001\Images\Temp_" & Me.ItemNumber.Text & "_" & Me.Year.Text & Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower


            '*** Save Images ***'  
            Me.FileUpload1.SaveAs(UlFileName)

            NewFileName = "\\bk00app0001\Images\" & Me.ItemNumber.Text & "_" & Me.Year.Text & Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower

            Dim objGraphic As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(UlFileName)

            Dim objBitmap As Bitmap
            '*** Calculate Height ***'  
            If intHeight > 0 Then
                objBitmap = New Bitmap(objGraphic, intWidth, intHeight)
            Else
                If objGraphic.Width > intWidth Then
                    Dim ratio As Double = objGraphic.Height / objGraphic.Width
                    intHeight = ratio * intWidth
                    objBitmap = New Bitmap(objGraphic, intWidth, intHeight)
                Else
                    objBitmap = New Bitmap(objGraphic)
                End If
            End If

            '*** Save As  ***'  
            objBitmap.Save(NewFileName, objGraphic.RawFormat)

            '*** Close ***'  
            objGraphic.Dispose()

            '*** Delete Original Image ***'
            File.Delete(UlFileName)

            '*** View Images ***'  
            Me.imgPicture.Visible = True
            Me.imgPicture.ImageUrl = NewFileName

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

After an image is uploaded it is not displaying on the web page like it should be:

```
                '*** View Images ***'  
            Me.imgPicture.Visible = True
            Me.imgPicture.ImageUrl = NewFileName
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a literal example of the contents of `NewFileName`? It looks like a network share path, or something, and also the `Image` control should be supplied a URL, not a physical file path.

Comment: first check for image url validity.

Comment: the network share path is "\\bk00app0001\Images\image.gif" How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your path incorrect, try to use  `Server.MapPath()`
Please read this documentation about [ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)